# extracting data using jsoup in java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to run this code and i am facing the **"Null Pointer Exception"** in my program.I used try and catch but i donot know how to eliminate the problem.
Here is the code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
public class WikiScraper  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
scrapeTopic("/wiki/Python");
}
public static void scrapeTopic(String url){
String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/"+url);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String contentText = doc.select("#mw-content-text>p").first().text();
    System.out.println(contentText);
    System.out.println("The url was malformed!");
}
public static String getUrl(String url){
URL urlObj = null;
try{
urlObj = new URL(url);
}
catch(MalformedURLException e){
System.out.println("The url was malformed!");
return "";
}
URLConnection urlCon = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
String outputText = "";
try{
urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
outputText += line;
}
in.close();
}catch(IOException e){
System.out.println("There was an error connecting to the URL");
return "";
}
return outputText;
}
}
```

**The Error shown is:**

```
There was an error connecting to the URL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hello.WikiScraper.scrapeTopic(WikiScraper.java:17)
    at hello.WikiScraper.main(WikiScraper.java:11)
```

Comment: Please remove the `<br/>` tags from your code and indent each line by 4 spaces to properly format it.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
public static String getUrl(String url){
    // ...
    return "";
}
```

What *always* ends in an empty String.

Try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
```

for example.